# Getting the line number of the definition of a function

Tags: python

I'd like to get the file path and line number of the definition of a given function (or method). I can use `inspect.getfile` for the path, but `inspect.getlineno` takes a frame, and that's where I get stuck.

I could probably get to my goal with something like this (that gives me the byte offset instead of the line number), but I can't help but think that there's a better way.

```py
import re
import inspect


def src_path_and_line_number(f):
    src_filepath = inspect.getfile(f)
    module = inspect.getmodule(f)
    module_src = inspect.getsource(module)
    f_src = inspect.getsource(f)
    m = re.search(re.escape(f_src), module_src, re.MULTILINE)
    if m:
        return src_filepath, m.start()
```

Example:

```py
>>> from pathlib import PosixPath
>>> src_path_and_line_number(PosixPath)
('.../.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/pathlib.py', 51265)
>>> src_path_and_line_number(PosixPath.glob)
('.../.pyenv/versions/3.8.6/lib/python3.8/pathlib.py', 37864)
```

*Note:
I know in some cases it won't work -- in fact, `inspect.getfile` doesn't always work either. But it's okay. Just as `inspect.getfile` is still useful, so would my linenumber information be useful when it is possible to get.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `inspect.getsourceline` do what you are after?

```py
>>> import inspect
>>> from pathlib import PosixPath
>>>> inspect.getsourcelines(PosixPath)[1]
1538
>>>> inspect.getsourcelines(PosixPath.glob)[1]
1121
```

Comment: It absolutely does. I tried it too, but didn't notice the number at the end. That was a waste of regex time! Thank.